# Can we say anything about $\gamma_n(G) \cap \zeta_{n-1}(G)$, where $\gamma_n(G)$ is lower central series and $\zeta_{n-1}(G)$ is upper central series?

Tags: group-theory, nilpotent-groups

Can we say anything about $\gamma_n(G) \cap \zeta_{n-1}(G)$, where $\gamma_n(G)$ is lower central series and $\zeta_{n-1}(G)$ is upper central series?

For example one can say $Z(G)\cap [G,G]$ is a subgroup of Frattini subgroup of G.

Comment: I was wondering if this intersection is contained in some term of upper central series…

Comment: The intersection is trivially contained in $\zeta_{n-1}(G)$ ...

Answer (score 4):

> **Proposition** Let $G$ be a group, Then for all $n \geq 0$,
> $$\gamma_{n+1}(G) \cap \zeta_n(G) \leq \Phi(G)$$.
>
> **Proof** Let $M$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. Then either $\zeta_n(G) \leq M$ or $G=M\zeta_n(G)$. In the latter case, $\gamma_{n+1}(G)=\gamma_{n+1}(M)$. In either case, $\gamma_{n+1}(G) \cap \zeta_n(G) \leq M$, so $\gamma_{n+1}(G) \cap \zeta_n(G) \leq \Phi(G)$ $\square$.

The theorem can be generalized to varieties of groups: if $\frak{V}$ is a variety of groups then $V(G) \cap V^*(G) \subseteq \Phi(G)$, where $V(G)$ is the *verbal* and $V^*(G)$ is the *marginal* subgroup of $G$, respectively. If one takes $\frak{V}=\frak{N}_n$, the variety of all nilpotent groups of class at most $n$, then one recovers the proposition above.